# Why Aren't expect(spy) and expect(obj["functionName"]) Identical?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine

I'm running Jasmine npm 2.5.3, and running the unit test via a web browser. The Spec Runner is testing multiple JS files, and when I run all tests, I get a test that fails, that shows the name of the test being in a completely different file, than the stack trace shown.

Here is the code from the stack trace:

[image]

It is failing on this

```
expect(get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expectedCalls);
```

line.

If I run either test one at a time, no issues. I did figure out that if I change the line that is in error to not reference the spy directly, there are no issues:

```
expect(webApi[spyFunctionName]).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expectedCalls);
```

I would have thought that expect(get) and expect(webApi[spyFunctionName])) would have been equivalent in this case.
Am I not understanding how spies work, or did I stumble onto a bug?

Here is the stack trace in case it is helpful:

```
Expected spy GetList to have been called 0 times. It was called 1 times.
    at stack (http://localhost:1130/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1640:17)
    at buildExpectationResult (http://localhost:1130/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1610:14)
    at Spec.expectationResultFactory (http://localhost:1130/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:655:18)
    at Spec.addExpectationResult (http://localhost:1130/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:342:34)
    at Expectation.addExpectationResult (http://localhost:1130/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:599:21)
    at Expectation.toHaveBeenCalledTimes (http://localhost:1130/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1564:12)
    at http://localhost:1130/test/spec/Allgnt.RestLibSpec.js:166:34
```

Comment: It looks like the spy is working (the error says `It was called 1 times.`) but the value of the variable `expectedCalls` is not what you think it is. So it looks like a bug in your logic rather than the spy

Comment: Everything is local to the function @slebetman.  Not sure what sort of bug I could have...

Comment: It depends. What's in the calls array? That's the source of `expectedCalls` and the first place you should debug.

Comment: It's an array of numbers.  What I don't understand is why `expect(get)` and `expect(webApi[spyFunctionName])` are different.